# Is there "Jedi magic"?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, the-force

In Sith knowledge, Sith sorcery and alchemy are considered categorically different from simple dark side powers.

Is there anything equivalent in status in the Jedi Order's repertoire: Jedi abilities and/or knowledge that are separate from simple neutral/light side powers?